# Portable way to redirect stdout and stderr to screen and a single file with headers for each

Tags: shell, unix

What would be a portable way to run a command and direct its stdout and stderr to both the screen and a log file, where the file has a header for each. The format of the log file would be something like:

```
*STDOUT*
foo
bar
blah
*STDERR*
more
stuff
```

Edit: Some more information in regards to questions brought up by @Jonathan and @Etan.

This command will be issued by a Python script, and the logging of stdout and stderr is needed for checking to ensure that the process ran correctly and that its output files can be carried onto the next step. For what it's worth, I have looked into the subprocess module and its ability to pipe stdout and stderr; however, there is a hard-coded limit on stdout memory within that module, so anything over 65K causes a deadlock.

The command is not interactive (in fact, if stdin is requested for whatever reason, the process should ideally be killed and that step flagged as having an error). Having the above format for the log file saves me a few lines of Python code for merging a stdout.log and stderr.log file (each process that Python runs needs to have a log file for it, not just for the script to parse later on, but also for humans to read to aid in debugging). As such, it's not absolutely required to do the above, but it would be nice (assuming it's easy to do, and most importantly, portable). It's important that the stdout and stderr are segregated, as certain processes should be flagged as failing if there is any stderr.

It's sounding like the most realistic approach will be to log the stdout and stderr in separate files using:

```
(cmd | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log
```

and then read, parse, and merge them into a single file within my Python script.

Comment: Is the command interactive?  If so, it is likely that redirection will mess up the prompting.  Assuming it is non-interactive, then you want to capture all the standard output after the heading `*STDOUT*` and then all the standard error after the heading `*STDERR*` — preferably leaving them interleaved normally on the screen?  That'll be tricky, I think.  I'm not sure if you'll be forced to go for pseudo-ttys.  Are you sure that's necessary, and desirable?

Comment: Do you need the output interleaved by line when displayed on the screen? Or is full buffering (and sorting) of output acceptable? Does this need to be done in a single command (or command line)? Can temporary files be used? What's the **exact** goal here? Please be specific about exactly how this program works (e.g. does it take input) and what characteristics of the output you need to preserve (e.g does output timing matter, does output order matter between stdout and stderr, etc.).